# Can someone solve level 6 of this logic game

Tags: algorithm, logic

I run into this game and manage to solve level one to five but not able to solve level six, I think it is recursive algorithm, sorry if this is not question for this site :)

Here is the link
http://ftzzle.42.us.org/index.html

Comment: sorry guys this is the proper link :) http://ftzzle.42.us.org/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Level 6:

```
White UpArrow, Green RightArrow, Red LeftArrow, and White F1.
```

Level 7:

```
White UpArrow, White UpArrow, Blue RightArrow, Blue F1, White F1.
```

Level 8:

```
White UpArrow, Red LeftArrow, White F1. Turn the speed to Fast because it takes a while.
```